# Windows - Contextual menu in OneDrive synchronized folders

Tags: windows, contextmenu, onedrive

My application has a contextual menu integrated in windows explorer: When right-clicking a file or a folder, an entry appears under which multiple actions are possible, kind of like TortoiseGit and many other applications.

However, in synchronized folders in OneDrive, the entry does not appear on online-only files (files that are not locally present on the disk). I noticed that many other menu entries do not appear either, including Windows Defender, Notepad++ and TortoiseGit.

The application interacts with the contextual menu by registering a COM object that implements the IShellExtInit and IContextMenu interfaces. While debugging, I noticed that unlike on normal files/folders, the method IShellExtInit::Initialize was not even called.

When enumerating the files of a folder containing such files using FindFirstFileW and FindNextFileW, these online-only files are found, and the application interacts with them naturally.

Is there any way to enable the contextual menu on these files?

Comment: i found a similar question on net. it seems that disabling `UAC` causes this: https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/95815-no-context-menu-onedrive-directory.html (you can check by changing the uac level and restart, or download and open `.reg` file and restart.). (however if your app should run on every computer, maybe you can tell the user about it and ask for user permission to change this reg key.)

Comment: @yaya Unfortunately this key is already at 1. Switching it to 0 seems to only disables the menu entries that are specific to OneDrive, while inside a OneDrive synchronised folder.